# Docker nginx multiple apps on one host

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I'm confused by how I should manage reverse proxy (nginx) with multiple independent webapps on the same host. I know that i can use https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy and configure VIRTUAL_HOST per app but then I wont be able to have nginx visible as a service in every app docker-compose.yml.

I want to do it this way because I want to clearly define all services needed to run app in production and replicate it easy in development.

In other words: I have two webapps that I need to run on the same host and I want to define nginx as a service dependency in docker-compose.yml in both apps but share that service with both as only one nginx can forward port 80.

Comment: Is `nginx` a requirement or a nice to have? Either way, I would look into something like `traefik`

Comment: So you have 2 projects, with 2 docker-compose.yml files. And you want just 1 nginx to serve them both? Are both projects running on the same port?

Comment: @ShawnC. it's a requirement as both project needs it for production

Comment: @sharif9876 they are not running on the same local port but nginx has to listen on port 80 and map it to local app port

Comment: Can we get an example of the 2 docker-compose files?

Answer (score 16):

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Test (test@example.com)
# install nginx
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-software-properties
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:nginx/stable
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
# deamon mode off
RUN echo "\ndaemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/nginx
# volume
VOLUME ["/etc/nginx/sites-enabled", "/etc/nginx/certs", "/var/log/nginx"]
# expose ports
EXPOSE 80 443
# add nginx conf
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
WORKDIR /etc/nginx
CMD ["nginx"]
```

**nginx.conf:**

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     test1.com www.test1.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://web1:81/;
    }
}
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     test2.com www.test2.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://web1:82/;
    }
}
```

** *where **web1** and **web2** - container names*

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "2"
services:
    web1:
        image: your_image
        container_name: web1
        ports:
            - 81:80
    web2:
        image: your_image
        container_name: web2
        ports:
            - 82:80
    nginx:
        build: .
        container_name: nginx
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        links:
            - web1
            - web2
```

**How to run:**

```
docker-compose up -d
```

When you call test1.com - nginx forwards your request to container web1:81, 
when test2.com - to container web2:82

P.S.: your question was about NGINX-reverse-proxy. But better and easier do this with TRAEFIK https://traefik.io

Comment: Now I see that my question wasn't that clear. web1 and web2 are two completely separate services that dont't have anything to do with eachother.

Comment: - if web1 and web2 are two completely separate services: 1) create attachable network. 2) web1 - attach to this network and web2 attach to this network.

Comment: but then nginx is separated container not included in any of docker compose files

Comment: Take a look also at this case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508505/how-to-run-docker-multiple-services-on-same-port

Comment: This did not seem to work on me, i ended up with a 502 bad gateway nginx error. I did some search and i found this https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/03/nginx-reverse-proxy-containerized-docker-applications/ which has the following lines
http {
    sendfile on;

    upstream docker-nginx {
        server nginx:80;
    }

    upstream docker-apache {
        server apache:80;
    }
....
are these necessary?

Comment: I got the same result as Nicolás. In my case it is not important if they are separate or closely related services, so I tried your solution anyway and got the same 502 error, it is only accessible by entering test1.com:81 and test2.com:82. By the way, could you explain the content you saw in the link you attached? StackOverflow removed it.

Comment: Shouldn't `proxy_pass  http://web1:82/;` be `proxy_pass  http://web2:82/;` ? Without that there is no reference to web2 in the nginx config and that would make the web2 container pointless

Answer (score 5):

You should also be able to open two ports in the same container

```
services:
web:
    image: your_image
    container_name: web
    ports:
        - 8080:80
        - 8081:81
```

And the add new config file for second app in nginx site-enabled (or conf.d) that will listen 81 port.

First App

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name localhost;
root /app/first;
}
```

Second App

```
server {
listen 81;
server_name localhost;
root /app/second;
}
```

So that:

- first app access on localhost:8080
- second app access on localhost:8081

Comment: What if I want to use https?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with django on production, turns out solving it is fairly straightforward.

The hack was to simply take the docker-compose.yml definition up a directory few levels. Making my file structure look something like this:

```
CodeRepo:
  app_0
  app_1
  app_2
  docker:
    docker-compose.yml
    config/nginx/conf:
      app_0.conf
      app_1.conf
      app_2.conf
```

Then the actual docker-compose file is defined as follows:

```
services:
      db:
        container_name: db
        image: postgres
        hostname: db
        env_file:
          - ../app_0/docker/.env.prod.db
        volumes:
          - app_0_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        networks:
          - app_0_backend
    
      app_0:
        build:
          context: ../app_0
          dockerfile: ../app_0/docker/Dockerfile.prod
        hostname: app_0_web
        env_file:
          - ../app_0/docker/.env.prod
        command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 app_0.wsgi --workers=4
        volumes:
          - static_volume_app_0:/app_0/static
          - media_volume_app_0:/app_0/media
        expose:
          - "8000"
        links:
          - db:db
        depends_on:
          - db
        networks:
          - nginx_network
          - app_1
        restart: on-failure
    
    
      app_1:
        build:
          context: ../app_1
          dockerfile: ../app_1/docker/Dockerfile.prod
        hostname: app_1_web
        env_file:
          - ../app_1/docker/.env.prod
        command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8001 app_1.wsgi --workers=4
        volumes:
          - static_volume_app_1:/app_1/static
          - media_volume_app_1:/app_1/media
        expose:
          - "8001"
        networks:
          - nginx_network
        restart: on-failure
    
      app_2:
        build:
          context: ../app_2
          dockerfile: ../app_2/docker/Dockerfile.prod
        hostname: app_2_web
        env_file:
          - ../app_2/docker/.env.prod
        command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8002 django_project.wsgi --workers=4
        volumes:
          - static_volume_app_2:/app_2/static
          - media_volume_app_2:/app_2/media
        expose:
          - "8002"
        networks:
          - nginx_network
        restart: on-failure
    
      nginx:
        container_name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.13
        ports:
          - "80:80"
          - "443:443"
```

Comment: `links` are a deprecated feature for your docker images config files. Prefer `networks` instead.